# Clojure string searching and counting

Tags: regex, clojure

I was wondering what the most Clojure-esque and standardised way of searching a string and returning boolean (or something falsy/truthy). (e.g In Java I would use .indexOf() and cast it to a boolean.)

What I want to do is search all the strings in a map and return 1 or 0, depending on whether the word "clouds" is in the string, and then find out the cumulative value at the end - I understand I can do this with regex, however I was wondering if there was an alternative?

Comment: just curious, why would we want to try an alternative to a regex?

Comment: I was curious as I don't use it enough for me (In my non-clojure job) to write something that would solve this basic problem very quickly, and.. was curious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually in Java the most natural solution is to use the `contains` method. You can do the same in Clojure:

```
(.contains "foobar" "bar")
;= true
```

Mapping over a seqable:

```
(mapv #(.contains "foobar" ^String %) ["foo" "bar"])
;= [true true]
```

With a map as input, you'd have to decide whether you want the keys, the values or both; depending on the answer, you'd want to use `keys`, `vals` or just map over the entries (in this case `reduce-kv` would yield a more performant solution than `map`).

This is assuming that you're searching for a literal substring (as with `indexOf`). With a regex, I'd use `re-find` and cast to `boolean` (it returns `nil` in absence of a match).

Comment: Thanks Michal, I was unaware of this method. (This will be useful)

Comment: I was wondering, could you explain what makes this a method and not a function?

Comment: These are just different concepts; the concept of a method comes from the JVM side, that of a function from the Clojure side. `contains` is a method of `java.lang.String`; `#(.contains "foobar" ^String %)` is a Clojure function which calls this Java method. Under the hood, Clojure functions are objects implementing the `clojure.lang.IFn` interface.

Comment: What does `^String` do here?

Comment: ^String is for type hint telling the compiler that the expression after it % should be of the type, see http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java Interop-Type Hints

Comment: Update, Clojure 1.8 added an `includes?` function to [clojure.string](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.string-api.html#clojure.string/includes?), which may be preferable to `.contains`.